# How do you create and run a single jar executable for a java project with Maven and external jars?

Tags: java, maven, jar

It could be a popular question, but I get completely different errors. I did everything as in the tutorials, but get an error, which I cannot fix. So, here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.softgile.asanapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>asanTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mis</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <systemPath>${basedir}\mis-service-toolkit-2.2.3-fatjar.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.softgile.asanapp.AsanEx</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I want to build and run the jar from the cmd. I use these commands:

```
mvn clean
```

It returns Build success
Then

```
mvn package
```

It also returns Build success
Then I use

```
java -jar asanTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

and get this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ee/cyber/asanimza/toolkit/MisClient
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ee.cyber.asanimza.toolkit.MisClient
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

How can I fix this issue and run the application from the cmd?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871065/classnotfoundexception-in-maven-project/16112614

Comment: thank you for the response, I have checked it, did the same and still get the same error